# LUT MLC when Neutral does not Connect to Light?

Tags: light-fixture, smart-switch, capacitor

I have a Lutron Caseta switch (PD-5S-DV) connected to a light. The LED on the switch is flashing red indicating that I need to add a LUT MLC to the circuit.

LUT MLC requires a hot (black) wire and a neutral (white) wire to work.

But as you can see in the image of my light fixture, the neutral wire isn't even connected to the light.

1. Can I still connect the LUT MLC to this fixture?
2. If so, should I still connect to both hot and neutral wires?
3. If this works, why does it work when the neutral wasn't used before?

[image: light fixture with ground and hot connecting to the light]

update: I've removed the cover and discovered that the ground is connected to where the white wire should go. There is a separate spot for the ground wire. Can I rewire this correctly or will that somehow cause problems with how it was set up before?

update 2: I've added a photo of the cover below

[image: back plate of light fixture]

Comment: Turn the breaker for that light off then test for continuity between neutral and ground at the fixture...

Comment: How do I test for continuity? What does testing for continuity achieve?

Comment: The LUT-MLC requires a *switched* hot and a neutral.    Lamps also need a switched-hot and a neutral.  If it is not neutral, what is that white wire?  Is your switch switching the neutral?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica -- I think the lamp is connected from switched hot to *ground*...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel *oh,snap...* this project just got a bit bigger...

Comment: Uh oh. Why is it a bigger project?

Comment: What suggestions do you have on how I solve this?

Comment: That's a weather-proof fixture attached to what very much looks like an exterior wall, yet there are 4 gaping holes (for conduit or other fixtures) that are _supposed_ to be filled with plugs to ensure they are actually weather-proof. Unless you just removed them and plan on reinstalling them (with some silicone to actually seal them), part of the "bigger project" includes purchasing the appropriate plugs. Check any of your other outdoor fixtures to see if they're missing their seals, too.

Comment: @merlinpatt -- can you get your paws on a multimeter?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I do have a multimeter

Comment: @FreeMan yes, I removed the plugs to access the wires and will reinstall them.

Comment: @merlinpatt -- can you turn the breaker for the circuit off, then put your multimeter on the function where it beeps if you put the probe tips together, then put one probe tip on the white wire in that box and the other probe tip on the bare grounds in that box?  (That's what I asked you to do with a *continuity* check...it checks to see if there's a low-resistance electrical path between the probes)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel just did that. What does this achieve and what am I looking for? I got no signal when I touched the white and neutral

Comment: @merlinpatt -- what you were looking for was your meter beeping at you to indicate continuity, or not beeping in case there is no continuity

Comment: @merlinpatt -- we also now know why this is a bigger project...there's a broken neutral somewhere upstream of this light, and that'll need to be rectified before we can continue here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109220/discussion-between-merlinpatt-and-threephaseeel).

Comment: To try and explain some of the continuity discussion - normally the light would receive electricity on the black wire, and then "return" that electricity by completing the circuit through the white wire. But instead, someone has used the bare ground wire to complete the circuit and the white wire is unused. The continuity test was to check if the neutral wire was in fact broken somewhere back along where it originated, and it seems like that is in fact the case. This explains why the bare wire was used instead -- but that is a very incorrect and potentially dangerous thing to do.